# Japanese character not displayed correctly which is hosted in iis7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, utf-8, iis-7, localization

I have `asp.net` mvc3 application which displays both English and Japanese characters in label and buttons. The English/Japanese characters are fetched from resource (`.resx`) file. I have hosted the site in local IIS. When I browse site from ISS, the Japanese characters are displayed correctly even if I use domain name or IP address.

Problem:

The same code I hosted in server machine IIS. When I use IP address and site name (For example, `http://10.111.11.11/sitename`) the Japanese characters are displayed correctly. All is fine.

But if I use domain name (For example, `http://abcd.mydomain.com/sitename`) the Japanese characters are displayed incorrectly.

What could be the problem? I have done some searches in net, but could not find any answer.

I am fetching Japanese words from `resources.ja-JP.resx` file. and in my `web.config` file added `<globalization culture='ja-JP uiCulture='ja-JP'>` and set thread culture and uiculture in code also. And tried this too in `web.config` `<globalization culture='auto' uiCulture='auto'>` but none of that is working.

If i use IP address, everything working fine, but if I use specific name it is not working?
Do i need change or add anything in code or IIS7?

Comment: @JakeGould i did not set utf-8

Comment: ok..if it is issue, then why it is displayed correctly when i use ip address?

Comment: Thanks jake, i think we need to change something in iis .net globalization. but i am not sure.  Anyhow thanks for info. I wil try ur suggestion, if it works, will mark as answer

Answer (score 1):

In your `web.config` you say you have this set:

```
<globalization culture='ja-JP uiCulture='ja-JP'>
```

Seems like you are missing a quote around the `culture='ja-JP` so it should be this:

```
<globalization
     culture="ja-JP"
     uiCulture="ja-JP"
  />
```

But do you also have the `utf-8` settings in place like this?

```
<globalization
     fileEncoding="utf-8"
     requestEncoding="utf-8"
     responseEncoding="utf-8"
     culture="ja-JP"
     uiCulture="ja-JP"
  />
```

Details from this [official Microsoft site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkak5b9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: i have put quotes correctly, but i did not add any encoding, i will try and update you soon